# Why does my scrapy JSON export not work when ran in Python?

Tags: python, terminal, scrapy, web-crawler

I've created a python scrapy script that I want to be able to start by running the python file and not using the terminal.

I've been using the following -

```
os.system("scrapy crawl preorder")
```

However, when I add a JSON export the scrapy it runs as normal but no JSON file is created. The same command works when ran in terminal.

```
os.system("scrapy crawl preorder -O test.json")
```

So why does the JSON export not work?

Here's the full code -

```
import scrapy, os

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class PreOrderSpider(scrapy.Spider): 
    name = 'preorder'
    start_urls = ['https://www.kapowtoys.co.uk/category/preorders.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for products in response.css('li.product'):
            try:
                yield{
                    'name': products.css('h2::text').get(),
                    'price': products.css('ins::text').get().replace('£',''),
                    'link': products.css('a').attrib['href'],
                }
            except:
                yield{
                    'name': products.css('h2::text').get(),
                    'price': 'unavailble', 
                    'link': products.css('a').attrib['href'],
                }

        next_page = response.css('a.next.page-numbers').attrib['href']
        if next_page is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
            # if next page exists parse again


os.system("scrapy crawl preorder -O test.json")
```

Comment: CHekc your scrapy projects root directory... it should be there

Comment: Comment by @alexander is correct. However as a side note, ensure to wrap your call to `os.system("scrapy crawl preorder -O test.json")` in `if __name__ =='__main__':` check to avoid errors related to circular imports.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. Because the terminal location defaults to the project directory I was looking for the file in the wrong place. Stupid, me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).